# modal does not print content included

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-plugins

I need to make a modal with printing functionality, I am using the [JQuery printThis plugin by Jason Day](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis) which works OK except when I test with an included file. It ignores / doesn't print the content of the included file.

Modal:

```
<div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Participe desta Promoção</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="printable">

                    THIS IS PRINTED

                    @include('default.modal-voucher')
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnPrint">PRINT</button>
            </div>

        </div>
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnPrint").click(function () {
    $(".printable").printThis({
         debug: false,
         printContainer: false,
         pageTitle: $("#info-modal .short-info .panel-headline-wrapper h1").html(),
         formValues: true,
         printDelay: 0
        })
});
```

});

The content: `@include('default.modal-voucher')` doesn't appear in print file, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Could be that it hasn't loaded yet? Can you put in a delay before it prints? I haven't come across @include. Are you using a framework?

Comment: When you show the popup (before you try to print) are you see the `include` content? Do you have a public URL so we could see it? `@include` is `php` syntax or other library/framework/language?

Comment: Im using the Laravel 5.2 framework. I solved the problem editing the call js.

Answer (score 0):

This way works for me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnPrint").click(function () {
    $("#print").printThis();
});
```

});

I got this in: [PrintThis Jquery plugin issue in Google Chroome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477200/printthis-jquery-plugin-issue-in-google-chroome) .